# automate whatsapp messages in .netcore 3.1 app

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, whatsapp

I'm currently working on a project where I aim to integrate a feature that notifies customers through WhatsApp when a purchase occurs. After researching online, it appears that WhatsApp does not offer a public API for this purpose. Considering the limited resources of our small and growing organization, I'm exploring cost-effective or free solutions. Is there a way to achieve this functionality without violating WhatsApp's terms or incurring substantial costs?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 [reached End Of Life a year ago](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). Why are you still using it? The oldest supported .NET Core version is .NET 6, supported until November 2024. The current Long Term Support version is .NET 8, supported until 2026

Comment: I'm working within an organization that currently utilizes the .NET 3.1 framework. As part of a project, I need to integrate a new feature. Considering the existing framework version, are there any specific considerations, best practices, or potential challenges I should be aware of when implementing this feature in .NET 3.1? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's dead. You shouldn't be using it, it hasn't received any fixes or even security updates in one year. A single organization doesn't change the fact this is no longer supported and would get you in trouble with any security or PCI audit. *Libraries* are abandoning it, which means you may have to use old library versions with bugs that were fixed in newer versions

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a Bussines WhatsApp account

Then you can use the [Meta API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/get-started)

[This](https://www.postman.com/meta/workspace/whatsapp-business-platform/folder/13382743-5d381d9d-db47-4ba3-bbac-bc3879785159) is a Postman collection for using the API

There you can find the way to send massages via WhatsApp API

This is a Curl Example from the postman collection above

```
curl -i -X POST \
https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{ "messaging_product": "whatsapp", "to": "TO_PHONE_NUMBER", "type": "template", "template": { "name": "hello_world", "language": { "code": "en_US" } } }'
```

That can be used in C# like this:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/FROM_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"); 

        request.Content = new StringContent("{ \"messaging_product\": \"whatsapp\", \"to\": \"TO_PHONE_NUMBER\", \"type\": \"template\", \"template\": { \"name\": \"hello_world\", \"language\": { \"code\": \"en_US\" } } }");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```